# JavaScript window.open() (and <a href="#" target="_blank"></a>) in Webkit notifications fails

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications

A [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/amjceojlfjidckejljbldjnmiebjmpab) I built a few months ago has been working fine until today. In the past, a user could click on the extension (or a link within the extension, in some cases) and a new tab would open in the browser. Now the new tabs are not opening. The strange thing is that the windows are opening somewhere. When I look at Manage Extensions, and I expand my extension, I can see the file names in the list of active views.

Here is a sample of the code being used:

```
window.open('newActivity.html');
```

and

```
Please <a href="http://chargetracker.appspot.com/" target="_blank">click here</a> to log in
```

Does anyone know why this would have stopped working? I'm using Chrome 18.0.1010.0 dev on Ubuntu 11.10. On this same machine, this whole thing is working with Chromium 15.0.874.106. I have had reports of this not working on Windows XP as well, though I don't know what version of Chrome.

Comment: Does it work in Canary or the latest Chromium? It might be a temporary bug.

Comment: Doesn't work on Canary. Haven't tested the latest Chromium.

Comment: Dev version may be buggy. I don't think that such a basic functionality was so drastically changed in a new version. For me (Chrome 16.0.912.75, Ubuntu 11.10) your extension works fine.

Comment: Well, I guess that answers my question. I suppose I'll go see if I can find that but on Chromium.org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a Chrome bug that affects the beta, dev and canary channels. I've reported it as [bug 111014](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=111014).